# How pass a parameter to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

In there i used this code to create `HTML` table using `JSON` , in my web program i generate `JSON` using `PHP` , now i need to pass the `JSON` as a parameter to above function, how can i do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
];
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;
    $.each(data[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
});
</script>
```

Can i pass the `JSON` value as parameter to this function using `PHP`

Comment: you can use ajax request to fetch json response. Please have a look into this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: how about you echo the `data` inside the function? I think thats the simplest way to do it.

Comment: It looks as if this is working. What are you trying to achieve? A good answer will depend on this.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer i need to generate table using json output, this code working fine, but json is generate by php, i need to pass that generated output to this function to generate table according to that php json output

Comment: @Rooter I asked, because I suspect that the json and the main page are actually created in two separate http requests. Is this true? If yes, you have to use ajax. If no, why didn't you accept one of the two answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass as parameter with php tags

```
   <?php
$data = '[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "rooter",
    "Password": "12345",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Email": "sac@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "binu",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "Binu@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "cal",
    "Password": "123",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "cal@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "nera",
    "Password": "1234",
    "Country": "uk",
    "Email": "nera@gmail.com"
  }
]';


?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $data; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
     $.each(data2, function(index, value){
         html += '<tr>';
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
        });
        html += '<tr>';
     });
     html += '</table>';
     $('body').html(html);
     console.log(html);
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Not working friend, can you provide me some complete tested code ,please. this provide me some error in this line $.each(<?php echo data[0] ?>, function(index, value){

Comment: Woow it's working friend :) thank u so much :)
and i have small question to ask,why another content not showing in php page with this jquery? suppose in this php also have <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>  but this  (Hello World ) is not showing , why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just creating your table in php so it's on the page when it loads, it will be much better for seo and user experience.

But this is how you can print javascript data when the page loads from php without having to make an ajax request.

The key is `<?= json_encode(array); ?>` json encode will parse a php array/associative array into a json object.

I did this in it's individual script tag in case there is an error with parsing or your editors syntax.

```
<?php                                                                                                             
$data = [                                                                                                         
  [ "UserID" => 1, "UserName" => "rooter", "Password" => "12345", "Country" => "UK", "Email" => "sac@gmail.com" ],
  [ "UserID" => 2, "UserName" => "binu", "Password" => "123", "Country" => "uk", "Email" => "Binu@gmail.com" ],   
];                                                                                                                
?>                                                                                                                
<script>data = <?= json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?></script>                                                                
$(document).ready(function () {                                                                                   
    var html = '<table class="table table-striped">';                                                             
    html += '<tr>';                                                                                               
    var flag = 0;                                                                                                 
    $.each(data[0], function(index, value){                                                                       
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';                                                                             
    });                                                                                                           
    html += '</tr>';                                                                                              
     $.each(data, function(index, value){                                                                         
         html += '<tr>';                                                                                          
        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){                                                                   
            html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';                                                                        
        });                                                                                                       
        html += '<tr>';                                                                                           
     });                                                                                                          
     html += '</table>';                                                                                          
     $('body').html(html);                                                                                        
});                                                                                                               
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it's working , unfortunately  my JSON is not generate like this,its generate like this, array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'UserID' => int 1
      public 'UserName' => string 'sachith' (length=7)
      public 'Password' => string '12345' (length=5)
      public 'Country' => string 'srilanka' (length=8)
      public 'Email' => string 'sac@gmail.com' (length=13)